# Apache Spark does not see all the ram of my machines

Tags: apache-spark, google-compute-engine, apache-spark-mllib

I have created a Spark cluster of 8 machines. Each machine have 104 GB of RAM and 16 virtual cores.

I seems that Spark only sees 42 GB of RAM per machine which is not correct. Do you know why Spark does not see all the RAM of the machines?

[image]

PS : I am using Apache Spark 1.2

Comment: Why do I have 3 downvotes? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a common misconception. What is displayed is the spark.storage.memoryFraction :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28363743/4278362

Answer (score 0):

Spark makes no attempt at guessing the available memory. Executors use as much memory as you specify with the `spark.executor.memory` setting. Looks like it's set to 42 GB.

Comment: spark.executor.memory was set to 83971m.