# Spark resources not fully allocated on Amazon EMR

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I'm trying to maximize cluster usage for a simple task.

Cluster is 1+2 x m3.xlarge, runnning Spark 1.3.1, Hadoop 2.4, Amazon AMI 3.7

The task reads all lines of a text file and parse them as csv.

When I spark-submit a task as a yarn-cluster mode, I get one of the following result:

- 0 executor: job waits infinitely until I manually kill it
- 1 executor: job under utilize resources with only 1 machine working
- OOM when I do not assign enough memory on the driver

What I would have expected:

- Spark driver run on cluster master with all memory available, plus 2 executors with 9404MB each (as defined by install-spark script).

Sometimes, when I get a "successful" execution with 1 executor, cloning and restarting the step ends up with 0 executor.

I created my cluster using this command:

```
aws emr --region us-east-1 create-cluster --name "Spark Test"
--ec2-attributes KeyName=mykey 
--ami-version 3.7.0 
--use-default-roles 
--instance-type m3.xlarge 
--instance-count 3 
--log-uri s3://mybucket/logs/ 
--bootstrap-actions Path=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark,Args=["-x"] 
--steps Name=Sample,Jar=s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,Args=[/home/hadoop/spark/bin/spark-submit,--master,yarn,--deploy-mode,cluster,--class,my.sample.spark.Sample,s3://mybucket/test/sample_2.10-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar,s3://mybucket/data/],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```

With some step variations including:

--driver-memory 8G --driver-cores 4 --num-executors 2

---

install-spark script with -x produces the following spark-defaults.conf:

```
$ cat spark-defaults.conf
spark.eventLog.enabled  false
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions         -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions         -Dspark.driver.log.level=INFO
spark.executor.instances        2
spark.executor.cores    4
spark.executor.memory   9404M
spark.default.parallelism       8
```

**Update 1**

I get the same behavior with a generic JavaWordCount example:

```
/home/hadoop/spark/bin/spark-submit --verbose --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 8G --class org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount /home/hadoop/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.3.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar s3://mybucket/data/
```

However, if I remove the '--driver-memory 8G', the task gets assigned 2 executors and finishes correctly.

So, what's the matter with driver-memory preventing my task to get executors?

Should the driver be executed on the cluster's master node alongside with Yarn master container as explained [here](http://badrit.com:8000/blog/2015/2/29/running-spark-on-yarn#.VXXXgvnBzRZ)?

How do I give more memory to my spark job driver? (Where collects and some other useful operations arise)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution to maximize cluster usage is to forget about the '-x' parameter when installing spark on EMR and to adjust executors memory and cores by hand.

This [post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) gives a pretty good explanation of how resources allocation is done when running Spark on YARN.

One important thing to remember is that all executors must have the same resources allocated!  As we speak, Spark does not support heterogeneous executors.  (Some work is currently being made to support GPUs but it's another topic)

So in order to get maximum memory allocated to the driver while maximizing memory to the executors, I should split my nodes like this (this [slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/SandyRyza/spark-job-failures-talk) gives good screenshots at page 25):

- Node 0 - Master (Yarn resource manager)
- Node 1 - NodeManager(Container(Driver) + Container(Executor))
- Node 2 - NodeManager(Container(Executor) + Container(Executor))

NOTE: Another option would be to `spark-submit` with `--master yarn --deploy-mode client` from the master node 0.  Are there any counter example this is a bad idea?

In my example, I can have at most have 3 executors of 2 vcores with 4736 MB each + a driver with same specs.

4736 memory is derived from the value of `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` defined in `/home/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml`.  On a m3.xlarge, it is set to 11520 mb (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/TaskConfiguration_H2.html) for all values associated to each instance types)

Then, we get:

(11520 - 1024) / 2 (executors per nodes) = 5248 => 5120 (rounded down to 256 mb increment as defined in yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb)

**7%** * 5120 = 367 rounded up to 384 (memory overhead) **will become 10% in spark 1.4**

5120 - 384 = 4736

Other interesting links:

- [Apache Spark: setting executor instances does not change the executors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940711/apache-spark-setting-executor-instances-does-not-change-the-executors)
- [Performance issues for spark on YARN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343788/performance-issues-for-spark-on-yarn)
- http://www.wdong.org/wordpress/blog/2015/01/08/spark-on-yarn-where-have-all-my-memory-gone/

Comment: Yep, basically user needs to tune settings to match what is desired.  The Spark docs regarding launching on yarn discuss this well.

Comment: Your node breakdown implies that the driver doesn't run on the resource manager (Master instance in EMR).  Is this the case?  (trying to wrap my head around all of this)  (when running as yarn-cluster)

Comment: Yes, that's what it says..  Unless I'm mistaken, I haven't seen anything running on master node when using yarn-cluster mode.

Comment: Thanks dude. I can't believe Amazon have messed this up so massively. I've been using EMR to run spark on YARN and have been scratching my head why only one vCPU was being used per node. I'd rather they just didn't bother setting defaults instead of setting cripplingly useless ones :-(

Comment: @MichelLemay thanks for the great answer, May i ask why you have subtracted 1024 from the memory of the node? is it reserved for the operating system?

Comment: @Rami  It's been a while since I played with theses settings.  Now, I'm usually using bigger machines and roughly rounding down memory limits.  However, I feel ashamed that I didn't put a reference or an explanation on it since I can't recall the exact meaning of this value.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is around the expectations for how Spark works on YARN.  When Spark is run with a deployment mode of cluster or master set to yarn-cluster the driver is *not* executed on the master node but in the Application Master container on one of the slave nodes. For more details see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

I expect what is happening is that the cluster cannot fulfill the memory requirements for the driver (remember that memory actually requested of the cluster is what you ask for plus an overhead) and thus waiting forever to allocate the Application Master where driver will run or for executors.

To give the driver the amount of memory you are requesting you would need to use additional slaves in order to provide resources for the cluster-based driver and executors at the same time.  With the overhead on the driver, I suspect you may need to utilize an instance type with more memory.  When you request 8G for the driver take a look at the resource manager log and verify the real amount requested.

To run the driver on the master node the deployment mode would need to be client.  This can still be done with EMR steps if you utilize one step to call a script to localize the driver jars onto the master node and then the next step can call spark-submit set for deployment mode client and referencing the JAR on the local master file system.

Comment: Then I would expect to always have at least one executor on a 3 machines setup.  When I look at the spark UI in the executor section, I often see one driver only and no executors.  And why does Spark not executing anything on the driver itself ?  That would seems reasonable to use the driver for some work.  However, it does not seems to be doing anything at all according to spark UI..

Comment: The driver is not for executor/parallel work. Just for anything collected back and the handling of the SparkContext interaction/scheduling. With a 3 machine setup there would be only 2 nodes for containers. If you see the driver but no executors... would have to look closer at the logs from the driver and resource manager to determine why an executor cannot turn up on the 2nd node.

Answer (score 1):

Michel Lemay's post is good background reading, and he gives an answer for 1 particular cluster configuration. I've embedded that logic into a spreadsheet that will show the best options for any cluster. To use, fill out the number of nodes in the cluster, the number of virtual cores/node, and the amount of allocatable memory/node. After doing this, the sheet will give you options for launch commands that will fully utilize your cluster for both client & cluster mode for 1, 2, 4, and 8 executors per node. I've highlighted the row corresponding to 2 executors per node as this has consistently been the best option in my tests. Feel free to copy this sheet or add tabs for different cluster types as you like.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VH7Qly308hoRPu5VoLIg0ceolrzen-nBktRFkXHRrY4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I get around the problem:

By setting spark.executor.memory + driver-memory below the total of any given MASTER node, then YARN is able to place both the Master and the executor on a given node.. You sacrifice some lost memory on the other nodes, but its more important that I have the CPUs running. Here is an example (on r3.8xlarge):

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-1234 --steps Type=Spark,Name=foob3,Args=[--conf,spark.memory.fraction=0.95,--conf,spark.memory.storageFraction=0.1,--conf,spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=8000,--conf,spark.executor.memory=200g,--conf,spark.executor.cores=32,--conf,spark.executor.instances=4,--conf,spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false,--class,myclass.Foo,--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,--driver-memory,10g,s3://myjar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```